Error while running Springboot Application integrated with hibernate Envers
I am trying to integrate Hibernate Envers into my project with Springboot version 2.6.3. As per the tutorials and documentation, I have added the required dependencies. Next step is that the Audit tables should be created automatically but I am getting the following error:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Receiver class org.hibernate.envers.internal.entities.RevisionTypeType does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract int getSqlType()' of interface org.hibernate.usertype.UserType.

Here in detail:
This is my dependencies:
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

<!-- Hibernate Core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.4.Final</version> <!-- Adjust version as per compatibility -->
</dependency>

<!-- Hibernate Envers -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.4.Final</version> <!-- Adjust version as per compatibility -->
</dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

My application.properties file :
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/enversDemo
spring.datasource.username=abcd
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
# Enable Hibernate Envers
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.integration.envers.enabled=true

I have made the versions of Hibernate - Core and Hibernate - Envers same,but I am getting this error:
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[2m2024-06-24T10:29:40.595+02:00[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m5892[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[enversdemo] [  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Receiver class org.hibernate.envers.internal.entities.RevisionTypeType does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract int getSqlType()' of interface org.hibernate.usertype.UserType.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:952) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at com.hibernateenvers.enversdemo.EnversdemoApplication.main(EnversdemoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.hibernate.envers.internal.entities.RevisionTypeType does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract int getSqlType()' of interface org.hibernate.usertype.UserType.
    at org.hibernate.type.internal.UserTypeSqlTypeAdapter.getJdbcTypeCode(UserTypeSqlTypeAdapter.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.JdbcType.getDefaultSqlTypeCode(JdbcType.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.spi.TypeConfiguration.addBasicTypeRegistrationContributions(TypeConfiguration.java:302) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:721) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:176) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1431) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1502) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:366) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1835) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    ... 20 common frames omitted

Please guide me what I am missing.

Which Spring Boot version is it for? Why are you defining an older hibernate dependency and not relying on spring-boot-starter-data-jpa? My advice is to always use the newest final versions of libraries.

Its Springboot version 2.6.3.When I try to use latest version, the dependencies aren't recognised and therefore not able to import

Do you mean javax.perisitence and javax.validation etc? Just rename javax to jakarta. This is the new package name for Spring Boot JPA since Spring Boot 3+. This is a known issue when using older tutorials.
